# AD FS log multiple ip extraction through Regex

Tags: regex, pcre

Stuck on pcre regex question.  I am trying to extract all ips following a field ("Client IP: ") in a AD FS log.
My log looks like this (truncated to save space):

```
EventCode=411
EventType=0
Type=Information
SidType=1
TaskCategory=Printers
OpCode=Info
Token Type: 
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/identitymodel/tokens/UserName  

Client IP: 
110.19.100.155,2603:1032:205:14::5 

Error message: 
******-This user can't sign in because this account is currently disabled
```

So the end result desired is that I get both ip addresses under the field src_ip, and that it only tries the regex if it finds the EventCode=411 or 512, etc...

What I have so far is this:

```
(\s\n|,)(?<src_ip>(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}(?:\d{1,3}))|(?:(?:::)?(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:{1,2}){1,7}(?:[\d\%A-Fa-z\.]+)?(?:::)?)|(?:::[\dA-Fa-f\.]{1,15})|(?:::))
```

This works but does not differentiate for events with only the required Event Codes. So when I do this:

```
(?ms)(?:EventCode=(411|512))\n.*?(\s\n|,)(?P<src_ip>(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}(?:\d{1,3}))|(?:(?:::)?(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:{1,2}){1,7}(?:[\d\%A-Fa-z\.]+)?(?:::)?)|(?:::[\dA-Fa-f\.]{1,15})|(?:::))
```

It only picks up the first ip.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/3StRMK/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may slightly modify your pattern by adding a custom boundary based on the `\G` operator that matches the start of a string or, what you need here, the end of the previous successful match:

```
(?ms)(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|EventCode=(411|512)\n.*?\R)\K(?P<src_ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}(?:\d{1,3})|(?:::)?(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{1,4}:{1,2}){1,7}[\d%A-Fa-f.]*(?:::)?|::[\dA-Fa-f.]{1,15}|::)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/giYl4Q/2).

Basically, the main difference is `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|EventCode=(411|512)\n.*?\R)\K`:

- `\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*` - the end of the preceding successful match (the start of string position has been subtracted with the negative lookahead `(?!\A)`), then a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `EventCode=(411|512)\n.*?\R` - `EventCode=` substring, then `(411|512)` captures `411` or `512` into Group 1, then `\R` matches a line break and `.*?\R` matches any amount of 0+ chars as few as possible up to another line break that will be followed with subsequent subpatterns)
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far from the whole match buffer.

You also had a slight issue: `[\d\%A-Fa-z\.]` should be written as `[\d\%A-Fa-f.]`.

Comment: This works perfectly in in the demo.  Unfortunately not so well in Splunk.  Thank you for the answer though, I will try to modify it to make it work for my use case.

Comment: @JoseG Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).